# C++ copy specified vector content to another vector

Tags: c++, vector, copy

I created a vector:

```
std::vector<std::string> mero; // earlier it filled with more than 500 data
```

After that I would like to create another vector which  only takes a portion of the `mero` vector. (example: from 100th to 250th)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a constructor for `std::vector` (number 4 in [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)) that takes two iterators. It constructs a new vector including all elements from the first iterator (inclusive) to the second iterator (exclusive).

```
std::vector<std::string> partOfMero(mero.begin() + 100, mero.begin() + 250);
```

This will include `mero[100]` through `mero[249]` in the newly-constructed vector.

Comment: Its confusing it doesnt include 250. The name in the definition says `[first, last]` is confusing

Answer (score 5):

`std::vector` has a constructor that takes two iterators, so you can specify a range to copy:

```
std::vector<std::string> v1;
std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator first = v1.begin() + 100;
std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator last = v1.begin() + 250;
std::vector<std::string> v2(first, last)
```

This will construct `v2` such that it contains copies of all the elements from `v1.begin()+100` to one before `v1.begin()+250`.